# Highlight search keyword in PHP does not highlight correctly

Tags: php, highlight, str-replace

I am trying to highlight my search result in PHP search but it highlights undesiraby

I use the code below

```
//connection to db
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'dbname');
define('DB_USERNAME','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if( mysqli_connect_error()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();


//get search term
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `location` FROM `locations` WHERE TRIM(location) LIKE '%".($_GET['term'])."%'");   

$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{

        $name = str_replace($searchTerm, "<span style='background-color:pink;'>$searchTerm</span>", $row['location']); 
        array_push($data, $name);   
}   



//return json data

echo json_encode($data);
```

Lets say I search for the term **makutano** 
I end up getting a result like the one displayed below:

[image]

I would expect it only to highlight `makutano`,  but it does not work as intended.

If i remove the `str_replace($searchTerm, "<span style='background-color:pink;'>$searchTerm</span>"` code my result would be as diplayed in the image below

[image]

My database location looks like

[image]

Where am i going wrong from my code? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You're pushing the information to JSON which is not really a good format for displaying information.

Comment: @JayBlanchard what should i have done. i am not so much good in this

Comment: Do it on your page through javascript instead of php.

Comment: You could concatenate the results and then echo that, rather than the JSON.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Which is the javascript code that i could use?

Comment: @JayBlanchard how do i go about that in my question.. 'concanate' any ideas?

Comment: I cant replicate your results running your code. Are you sure thats all of it?

Comment: You have an SQL-injection vulnerability in your code. Either escape `$_GET['term']` or use parameterized queries (examples: http://codular.com/php-mysqli).

Comment: @DevDonkey i have edited my question for more elaboration

Comment: @sba i will fix that . can you solve the highlight issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the information you have to concatenate a string (which I do with the `implode()`)instead of creating a JSON object:

```
//get search term
$searchTerm = htmlspecialchars($_GET['term']);

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `location` FROM `locations` WHERE TRIM(`location`) LIKE '%".($_GET['term'])."%'");   

$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $name = $row['location']; 
    array_push($data, $name);   
}   

$string = '"' . implode('","', $data) . '"';
$newString = str_replace($searchTerm, "<span style='background-color:pink;'>$searchTerm</span>", $string); 
echo $newString;
```

Once you have created a string then you can do the replace to add the markup to the string.

---

[Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). I have done the bare minimum in this code by using `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: the highlighting works great but it eliminates the quotes. between the words e.g. `"machakos mwala makutano mwala"`,

Comment: Edited to add the quoting @OmariOmosa